# Derivative of $\text{trace}(U^T x y^T V)$ with respect to $x$

Tags: matrix-calculus

I'm trying to compute the derivative of $\text{trace}(U^T x y^T V)$ with respect to $x$, where $U \in \mathbb{R}^{d_x \times k}$, $V \in \mathbb{R}^{d_y \times k}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d_x}$, and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{d_y}$.

I have so far computed the derivative regarding $U$ and $V$, which are:

$$\frac{\partial \text{trace}(U^T x y^T V)}{\partial U} = x y^T V$$
$$\frac{\partial \text{trace}(U^T x y^T V)}{\partial V} = y x^T U$$

For this other derivative, I tried to use rule 101 from [Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), but the shapes aren't matching.

$$\frac{\partial \text{trace}(U^T x y^T V)}{\partial U} = V^T y U$$

whose shapes are $(k \times d_y) (d_y \times 1) (d_x \times k)$.

[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivate+trace(U%27+X+Y%27+V)+with+respect+to+X) gave me $V U^T y^T \cdot \text{trace}(V x U^T y^T)$, in which if I pick the first term, shapes are correct, $(d_y \times k) (k \times d_x) (d_x \times 1)$.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace of a matrix equals the trace of its transpose
$${\rm tr}(M)={\rm tr}(M^T)$$
Cyclically permuting the arguments of a trace does not change its value
$${\rm tr}(ABC)={\rm tr}(CAB)={\rm tr}(BCA)$$
Apply these two facts to your third expression
$$\eqalign{
{\rm tr}(U^Txy^TV)
 &= {\rm tr}(V^Tyx^TU)
  = {\rm tr}(x^TUV^Ty) \cr
}$$
This has the same form as your first expression, therefore its derivative must be
$$UV^Ty$$